# Countdown timer does not stopping at 0

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

Questions about responsive Bootstrap Countdown Timer. Like in this example: https://codepen.io/hemasundar/pen/bqwKeP

How can we make the timer stop at zero?

```js
            // set the date we're counting down to
            var target_date = new Date("10-24-2022 21:50:20").getTime();

            // variables for time units
            var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

            // get tag element
            var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

            // update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
            setInterval(function () {
                // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
                var current_date = new Date().getTime();
                var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

                // do some time calculations
                days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
                seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

                hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
                seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

                minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
                seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

                // format countdown string + set tag value
                countdown.innerHTML =
                    '<span class="days">' +
                    days +
                    ' <label>Days</label></span> <span class="hours">' +
                    hours +
                    ' <label>Hours</label></span> <span class="minutes">' +
                    minutes +
                    ' <label>Minutes</label></span> <span class="seconds">' +
                    seconds +
                    " <label>Seconds</label></span>";
            }, 1000);
```

I have tried different models but without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the interval if the days reach Zero.

```js
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date('April, 1, 2017').getTime();
 
// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
 
// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
 
// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
var interval = setInterval(function () {
 
    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
 
    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
     
    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
     
    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);
    if (days == 0){ // you can add seconds too like (days== 0 || seconds == 0)
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = '<span class="days">' + days +  ' <label>Days</label></span> <span class="hours">' + hours + ' <label>Hours</label></span> <span class="minutes">'
    + minutes + ' <label>Minutes</label></span> <span class="seconds">' + seconds + ' <label>Seconds</label></span>';  
 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Are there other options to make it stop at zero automatically?

Comment: @StefanAdriaans with interval logic as per my knowledge no.